# How does Google autocomplete know what error I just threw?

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete

Can someone help me understand why sometimes when getting errors, whether they be PHP browser errors or console javascript errors, Google's autocomplete feature seems to detect it before it should enough of the error has been reasonably completed?  It is possible that they detect browser errors in Chrome and weight autocomplete results with it?

Answer (score 0):

Google remembers all queries from all users. Common queries are auto completed with help from the data from the saved queries. 
Other users have searched for the same exact error before you did, so google tries to guess which error you want to enter.